# How to convert hex UTF-16 char to string in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm working on a function to correctly display Arabic words on the display/LCD. (Arabic letters have four different modes.)
I have an array of Arabic letters (`Map array`) in different states.
After recognizing the alphabet in Arabic, I need to re-align the letters.
My question is how do I put the Unicode characters through the table (`Map Table`) to a `String variable` (pBuffer)?

For example: To write the word `باب` you need to select the letter from `Map table` and place it in a `String` to send to the display/LCD.

```
...
const unsigned char Map[][5] PROGMEM = {

     /* code, isolated, initial, medial, final */
    {0x0621, 0xFE80, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000 },  //1 /* HAMZA ء*/
    {0x0622, 0xFE81, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFE82 },  //2/* ALEF_MADDA آ*/
    {0x0623, 0xFE83, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFE84 },  //3/* ALEF_HAMZA_ABOVE أ*/
    {0x0624, 0xFE85, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFE86 },  //4/* WAW_HAMZA ؤ*/
    {0x0625, 0xFE87, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFE88 },  //5/* ALEF_HAMZA_BELOW إ*/
    {0x0626, 0xFE89, 0xFE8B, 0xFE8C, 0xFE8A },  //6/* YEH_HAMZA ئ*/
    {0x0627, 0xFE8D, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFE8E },  //7/* ALEF ا*/
    {0x0628, 0xFE8F, 0xFE91, 0xFE92, 0xFE90 }   //8/* BEH ب*/
};

String pBuffer;
pBuffer += ((char)(Map[7][4]));
pBuffer += ((char)(Map[6][6]));
pBuffer += ((char)(Map[7][3]));

u8g2.setCursor(5, 20);
u8g2.print(pBuffer);
...
```

Unfortunately the above method used does not work.
How do I select characters from the "Map" table above and put them together in a `String` variable?

Comment: Didn't the compiler issue any warnings, as these numbers do not even fit unsigned chars

Comment: No warnings, I also have no output on the display.

Comment: Then time to ensure you're compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` or similar

Comment: I use Arduino. How can flags be used when compiling?

Comment: The problem is that the characters are UTF-16 and I don't know how to convert any HEX code into a character equivalent for print. https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: I know but how you can see where you're driving if your windshield is covered in mud

Comment: You can use hex escapes in *string literals* for your letters. Or write the entire file in utf8 with these letterforms in there in quotes

Comment: @Miranda utf-16 characters should be inside `char16_t` variables. For utf-8, you need either `char8_t` if your compiler supports it or simply `char`.

Comment: The question says the characters are `UTF-8` but now you say they are `UTF-16`? Maybe update the question?

Comment: It looks like you needto convert `UTF-16` to `UTF-8`. Does Arduino support the standard library conversion routines?

Comment: @Galik I have no information about this, but is there a way to put characters in a `String` variable?

Comment: @Miranda `String` is not something from the standard library. Without knowing the implementation, it's hard to answer

Comment: There will be a way but  how much work depends on what you already have available. I don't know much about Arduino's libraries tbh.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot If I want to save the results in `char variable` instead of `strings variable`, what is the solution? I want to convert hex codes to characters and put them in a `char variable` so that I can display them on the screen.

Comment: It seems to me the codes you are storing in your table probably need to be in type `char16_t` not `unsigned char`. Then you need a function that takes a `UTF-16` character or a pair of `UTF-16` surrogates and converts them into `UTF-8` in an `unsigned char` buffer.

Comment: @Galik Yes, that's right, I need exactly that.

Comment: @Miranda, a single `unsigned char` cannot represent an Arabic character in ASCII, UTF-8, or UTF-16. You *must* use the Arduino's `String` class to store a unicode character. Are you also sure that the Arduino screen you're using has support for Unicode characters too?

Comment: @Romen I use u8g2 library in arduino and support unicode character o OLED screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I must suggest that you look up the UTF-8 values for those Arabic characters. Arduino and u8g2 both support UTF-8 encoding but not UTF-16. It is much more straightforward to solve this problem when starting with an array of UTF-8 values.

For UTF-8 characters, the compiler can convert **code points** inside string literals for you:

```c++
String character = u8"\u0628"; // ب
```

Internally that string will contain two bytes that represent "ب" in UTF-8.
A single `char` is not enough storage space for *any* Arabic character in UTF-8 or UTF-16, so you must use an array (`char*`) or a `String`.

The Arduino IDE allows you to just write Unicode character literals directly in the code too:

```c++
String character = "ب";
```

As long as the source code is saved in UTF-8 format, the string will be the same as above with the `u8"\u0628"` value.

You could rewrite your character map to use a `String`, and then just type in the Arabic characters literally or using the code point method: (using accented latin characters for example here)

```c++
const String Map[][5] PROGMEM = {
  {"a", "à", "á", "A", "Á"},
  {"e", "è", "é", "E", "É"}
};
```

Of course the `String` will use more than 2 bytes to store those characters, so you can save space by storing the characters as 16-bit integers, but you will have to do some conversion before-hand.

A Unicode code point is not actually the binary representation that you will see in the character buffer. `U+0628 = ب` but the actual binary representation is `0xD8A8`. *That* this the value you should store in the Map, not the codepoint (`0x0628`) like you have already.

```c++
const uint16_t Map[][5] PROGMEM = {
  {0xD8A8, ..., ..., ...},
  ...
};
```

If you use `String` for your map, you can easily build strings from it:

```c++
String output = Map[i][2] + Map[j][3] + Map[k][4];
```

If you use `uint16_t`, then you have to split the integer value into two bytes to add a character:

```c++
uint16_t v = Map[i][j];  // v = 0xD8A8 for example
char lo = v & 0xFF;   // The D8 part of 0xD8A8, lo = 0xD8
char hi = v >> 8;     // The A8 part of 0xD8A8, hi = 0xA8
String output = String(hi) + String(lo); // output = {0xA8, 0xD8}
```

Lastly, you will have to convert the `String` to a `char*` buffer for using with `U8g2::drawUTF8()`. You can do that by using `output.c_str()` to get the underlying `char*` buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution but my question still is how to convert UTF-16 Hex to a character (That is, converting two bytes (UTF-16) to a character and then saving it to a `string` variable)?

Comment: Also, the new problem with the method introduced by you is that this method consumes a lot of memory and when compiling, I get a memory error. (not enough memory)

Comment: @Miranda, I have updated my answer with a solution that should use less storage space and a proper method to convert hex values to UTF-8 strings.

Comment: Unbelievably, this new method doesn't work. It works fine when I enter the value manually [for example: String output =  String("\u0628") ], but I couldn't find a way to extract it from the uint16_t Map table. it is interesting, the String output = String(hi) + String(lo)  command does not work and there is no output on display. The format must be in \u0628

Comment: @Miranda, It seems round-about to build a string like `"\u0628"` at run-time. I tested the `String(hi) + String(lo)` method on an arduino emulator with `Serial.print` and got the correct Arabic character, so does that line not compile? Or does it just give a `String` that doesn't work with the `u8g2` display function?

Comment: I used String(hi) + String(lo) on `u8g2` and output is unclear (The program is compiled successfully.). but when I'm using the `\u0628` format, that's all right.

Comment: The problem is solved if the `Map` table data is converted to `u0628` like format and then sent to `u8g2.print` function. that's mean `0x0628` convert to `\u0628`. Also, using "\u0628" format in the `Map` table greatly increases the table size so the table data needs to be converted at runtime.

Comment: @Miranda, I'm not sure that you *can* build a string with `\u` at run-time. The escaped characters are surely useful at compile-time, but I'm not sure that there is a way to append an "escaped character" to a `String`. Can you confirm that the `String(hi) + String(lo)` method with `u8g2.print` does not print `ب` when you start with a hard-coded `uint16_t v = 0xD8A8`?

Comment: with `uint16_t v = 0xD8A8` and `u8g2.print(v)` output is `55464`, and also with `u8g2.print(char(v))` is unclear and rubbish. also `String(hi) + String(lo)` is unclear and not `ب` and etc!

Comment: @Miranda, Could you humour me and post the output you get from `String(hi) + String(lo)`? The first two methods you posted in your last comment are not valid ways to convert the UTF-8 character (2 bytes) into a String that `u8g2.print()` will recognize as UTF-8. Also, please try it with `u8g2.drawUTF8()` as I suggested in the answer. The regular `u8g2.print()` method may be the issue here.

Comment: with `u8g2.drawUTF8(x, y, v)` screen is blank. also before `u8g2.print()` function I used `u8g2.enableUTF8Print()` for enable `UTF8` print. output for u8g2.print("\u0628") is correct and that's `ب`

Comment: @Miranda, I see that you're trying to print `v` directly, that is a 16-bit unsigned integer. Most `print` methods are going to print the decimal value that `v` contains because `uint16_t` represents a number. You *need* to split that 16-bit number into the high and low bytes and then concatenate them as two `char` or `String` values into a `String`. That 16-bit number just happens to be identical to the two byte values (in sequence) that represent the single UTF-8 character..

Comment: Thanks Romen, My code and output: https://gist.github.com/idreamsi/8b01321006c8391b784940ad77578e9d

Comment: @Miranda, `uint16_t v = 0x0628;` is using the **code point**, which is not correct for UTF-8. You need to use `uint16_t v = 0xD8A8;` for that character, because that is the actual binary representation of the U+0628 character in UTF-8 encoding. I believe I explained this in my answer, so please make sure you read it fully.